# ASP.NET C# File Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, filesystems

Architecture of my "*ImageDemo*" application

Technology : ASP.NET
Language : C#

**Previous architecture:**
The asp.net pages are stored in the webserver. 
A folder named *ImageRepository* is exist in the webserver. I do store the images (browsed, selected, and stored by users) in the *ImageRepository*. I could access all the attributes and content of the images stored in *ImageRepository*. I used to display images using *Image* control of ASP.NET.

**New architecture:**
Instead of storing the images in a folder of the webserver, I do setup a dedicated *Files Server* with the following credentials(say)

user name : my_name

password  : wXy12Apl

I **could** login to the system, access the folder where I stored the images, read the all attributes of the files. Then I added the file name to a dropdown list,so it will look ;like this

[image]

So on the *onselectedindexchanged* event I tried to display the images using *Image* control of ASP.NET. But I could not. What will be the problem? I could access all the attributes of the files, but I could not read the **content** of image.

For eg; When I select first image, the contol looks like
[image]

When I select second image, the contol looks like
[image]

Comment: Post some relevant code please.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have permission to the file.  You can do like @Smudge202 suggests and apply the correct permissions, or you can run part of your code in a different context.  See this code for impersonating a user: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The browser / end-user does not have access to the file server.  There are a couple quick solutions you can implement:

1)  Add permission for end users to read from the new file share - if your site is internal (on a LAN only) then this is possibly the best solution.  If the site is exposed to the internet this may not prove to be the most secure solution.

2)  Create a simple web service (WCF or ASMX).  Ensure the service can read from the new share, and have the service return the content as a webresponse.

Here is an (almost complete) example of the latter, an old piece of code responding from the old style asp.net handler (ashx) which implements [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - I'd recommend using WCF personally:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    _Context = context
    _Context.Response.Clear()
    _Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
    If ImageParameter IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim imageData As Byte() = Nothing
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageParameter.CompressedFileStorageLocation) Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim imagePath As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", CS_IMAGE_REPOSITORY_BASE_PATH, ImageParameter.CompressedFileStorageLocation)
        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(imagePath) Then
                Using s As FileStream = New FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open)
                    ReDim imageData(s.Length)
                    Dim bytesRead As Integer = s.Read(imageData, 0, s.Length)
                    s.Close()
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try

        _Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
    End If

End Sub
```